# Declare variable in the beginning of a html document

Tags: javascript, variables

In PHP we can declare variables in the beginning of the document this way:

```
<?php
$title="Title of the webpage";
?>
```

In the html code this title will replace the `echo $title` in the html code of the webpage.
Is it possible to do it using html and Javascript, I mean without using PHP?

Comment: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/variables

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title

Comment: The title is incorrect as it implies a document can have variables. It's actually the script within a page that can have variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
var someVariable="someValue";
document.title = someVariable;
</script>
```

Comment: document.write is extremely outdated.

Comment: @jbabey: It complete depends on what you are trying to do... in this case (setting the `title` content), `document.write` would be a relatively easy way to set the content. It won't work work in XHTML documents though. It's similar to the discussion about `eval`. It's only evil if used wrongly.

Comment: @FelixKling i disagree, there is never a reason to use `document.write` outside of testing scenarios. Similarly, there is never a reason to use `eval`. Keep in mind these are just opinions :P

Comment: @jbabey: Right, and comments are no place to argue about such things anyway :) Actually in this situation `document.title = ...` would really be the better approach, but I was just thinking about situations where you don't have an easy access to an element... anyways, does not make sense to continue this...

Comment: when I used this <SCRIPT language=javascript>document.write(title)</SCRIPT> it is written as it is. even with the "<SCRIPT language=javascript>"...........